# Read email one at a time using IMap4Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap

I'm reading emails using Imap. My code, which is working, is as follows:

```
Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox("inbox");  
MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse("UNSEEN"); 
return messages;
```

But I want to get one email at a time instead of getting all the messages as a MessageCollection. I don't want to loop through MessageCollection either. Is there any method which returns only one message?

For example :

```
Message email = mails.Search("UNSEEN");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why you want to get one email at time because I'm sure it will only return collection like all unread or all unseen. Is there any reason for it where you want to get one email at a time?

Comment: I'm reading all the 'unseen emails', retrieve certain information  and insert into database. But when there's error, all the emails status have been changed to 'seen'. So, I need to read one email at a time, so that I won't lost any unseen new emails.

Comment: There is no direct method for this. But this project is open source so you can modify and then create a dll

Comment: Looks like a simple change; in Fetch.cs, change a few occurences of " body[" to " body.peek[". (body.peek is IMAPspeak for "access the body and don't mark the message as seen".)

Answer (score 1):

You can Find the below solution

```
        Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client();
        imap.ConnectSsl("imap.gmail.com", 993);
        imap.Login("abc@gmail.com", "thatsmypassword");
        imap.Command("capability");

        Mailbox inbox = imap.SelectMailbox("inbox");
        int[] ids = inbox.Search("UNSEEN");
        if (ids.Length > 0)
        {
            Message msg_first = inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(ids[0]);
        }
```

Thanks,
Gauttam

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out my problem